# How do I make a keyboard shortcut open an existing window?

Tags: shortcut-keys

`Ctrl + Alt + T` opens a *new* terminal window. How do I make a keyboard shortcut open an existing window for an application if one is already open (and open a new one if not)?

Comment: Have you used `Alt`+`Tab` yet? That's a quick solution for selecting an existing window. As far as a hot key for opening your favourite applications there are many approaches for that.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I do use `Alt`+`Tab`, but that's not quite what I need here. I want a shortcut to immediately bring up, say, a termimal, but if there's already a terminal window open I want to switch back to it, not create a new one. That way I don't have to think about whether or not I already have a terminal window open; I just press my shortcut key and I'm always looking at a terminal (without creating a bunch of extra windows every time I press it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **basic way** to run-or-raise an application, i.e., switch to it if it is running, else run it, is a one-line terminal command. It  uses `wmctrl`. Install it with `sudo apt install wmctrl`. Then enter the following command for your shortcut key:

```
sh -c "wmctrl -x -a Gnome-terminal || gnome-terminal"
```

`wmctrl` checks if a window with class `Gnome-terminal` exists. If that fail (`||`) the second command is executed, which is just launching a new instance of gnome-terminal. `sh -c` is needed to wrap it all in a single command.

You can find the window class of an open window by running `xprop | grep WM_CLASS` in a terminal, then clicking on the window.

You can delete the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> keybinding and replace it by your own custom version.

An **option on steroids** that I use is a script [jumpapp](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp). The [GitHub page](https://github.com/mkropat/jumpapp) explains how to install it in Ubuntu as a .deb package, so it is registered in the package management system. The command for your shortcut key becomes as simple as:

```
jumpapp gnome-terminal
```

The added value over the basic way is that `jumpapp` will allow you to cycle through multiple open windows when you repeatedly hit the shortcut key, and can accomodate some specific cases. Read all about it in the excellent `man` page, `man jumpapp`.

Comment: I like this. Even though I've used `wmctrl` a couple of times I would never have thought of it.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH!

Answer (score 1):

xdotool windowactivate --sync $id     ..............   $id from ids=$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "$name")  ... $name is for U
then set shortcut key for it from script or multi command line command

> id=$(xdotool search --desktop 0 --class  "firefox"); echo "$id";
> xdotool windowactivate  "$id"

. caution as firefox will have 2 ids if you have the download manager also opened.

Comment: for not opened run a script that checks if no $id comes up., then launch it , else activate as above then command '   bash !/MyScripts/activatefirefox.sh ' .. that search will give an array if more than one, none if none

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative, you can pin the terminal to your taskbar, and use <kbd>Meta/Windows</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd> shortcut

Eg: If you pinned it at 2nd position, use <kbd>Meta</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>